# How to find a dynamic Match with a Pattern

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

Ok, so i have been looking for the answer a little bit but cant find any sort of answer to this:

I am creating a file on my mobile and want to write the following:

If a line with this pattern "N:xval,yval" exists for the number N, and furthermore xval and yval arent set, then i want to replace that line with "N:xval+1,yval+{0 or 1}" 
If there is no line like this i want to create a new line with "N:1,{0 or 1}"

THE ISSUE: it doesnt find a Match

i am at this state:

```
for (int N=0; N<myNumber; N++){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+):(\\d+),(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(""+myNumber+":(\\d+),(\\d+)");
    m.find();

    int xval, yval, val;
    if (m.matches()) {
        val =Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        xval = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        yval = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        ++xval;
        if (myBoolean==true){
            ++yval;
        }
        line = String.format("%d:%d,%d", val ,xval, yval);
        try {
            globalwriter.write(line.getBytes(), m.start(), line.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        int zeroorone;
        if (myBool==true){
            zeroorone=1;
        }else{
            zeroorone=0;
        }
        line = String.format("%d:%d,%d \n ", myNumber ,1, zeroorone);
        try {
            int end;
            if (checker.length() == 0){
                end = 0;
            }else{
                end = (int)checker.length() -1;
            }
            globalwriter.write(line.getBytes(),(int) end,line.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for replys

Answer (score 0):

p.matcher() needs to be the String you are trying to match, not a regular expression.

Try moving the regular expression to the Pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(""+myNumber+":(\\d+),(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
```

edit: inputString should be in the "N:xval,yval" format

Comment: but how do i fill the `inputString` when i dont know what xval and yval are. again with the `(//d+)` ?

Comment: @jacobusConradi You said you were checking a line for a pattern, that line should be `inputString`.